# importing images with magmi 99% complete

Tags: magento, magmi

Im having a problem with Magmi Image Attribute Processor.

Most of my images are uploaded, yet some dont get updated.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => '568140',
    'sku' => '568140',
    'image' => '568140_0.jpg',
    'small_image' => '568140_0.jpg',
    'thumbnail' => '568140_0.jpg',
    'media_gallery' => '568140_1.jpg',
);
```

**ATTEMPTED**

- using images that works on other products
- tried every url build up
- checking for chmod/logs
- deleting product (multiple times)
- with and without/ changing store columnm

**UPDATE**

the problem was in the migration of folders between 2 servers. the rights on some subfolders were different then others. fixed rights and it worked again.

Comment: have you configured the plugin to "override existing images" ? since by default, it keeps existing images if found.

Comment: Hi dweeves, yes it is on 'override existing images'

Comment: any warning or errors on log ?

Comment: that is also a problem, i see no logs

Comment: you seem to use datapump api since you describe your data in php. in that case you need to initialize the datapump instance with a specific logger. by default, i think it'll use the default magmi logger that should put a file in magmi/state/progress.txt

Comment: Thank you that might be usefull, i will get into that :) ps. sent you a email.